# AjaxForm with multiple id

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, ajaxform

i have a comment field on each div generated automatically. only on first post the ajax will work without refreshing the page.

`while($fimage = mysql_fetch_assoc($followers)){ 
 .........`

```
    <form class="commentFiled"  method='post' id="comment" name="comment"   
action="func/post_comment.php" >
    <input  required type="text"  id="com" name="com" placeholder="Write a comment..." style="width:97%; height: 45px;"
    class="commentTextField">
    <input type="hidden" name="p" value="<?php echo $disid ?>" id="photo" />
    </form>
```

my `ajaxForm`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$("#comment").ajaxForm( {
target: '#wtf', 
success: function() { 
$('#com').val('');
$('#com').blur();
//$('#da').slideUp('fast'); 
} 
});
```

what i want is that on each post when i post it doesn't refresh, the form doesn't get the second post `ID` i guess. , could you tell me what i should do ? because i'm lost here. thanks

Comment: Don't use the same `id` attribute more than once on the same page: it's invalid html, and logically how could the JavaScript work? When you say `$('#com').val('');` how would it know which of the multiple `id="com"` elements you are trying to clear?

Comment: @nnnnnn what do u mean ? where i am using the same id ?

Comment: @nnnnnn com is the textarea !

Comment: just add an iteration and use "comment_" . $i. By this you can have id's with numbers. Then before using AJAX, group all submitted forms and send it. Or send multiple AJAX requests (but I don't recommend it). Or handle the form through php.

Comment: _"where i am using the same id?"_ - I thought you were creating multiple forms of that structure with a php while loop. Is that _not_ what you're doing?

Comment: the textfield is generated automatically yeah using php. but my problem is not with clearing the value of the field. my problem is that the comment is posted to the first post which is the first id. that's my issue. !

Comment: Your problem (again) is that by creating multiple forms in a loop you're giving every form the same id. Within each form the input has the same id every time. And then within your JavaScript you try to refer to them by id which only finds the first one. You should (a) fix your php to _not_ use the same ids (or just remove the ids, you don't really need them) and then (b) change your JavaScript to use the class instead, and within the success function use DOM navigation methods to find the input that belongs to the current form. Mr Foscarini's answer gives you the basic structure for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use class name like this:

```
$(".commentFiled").ajaxForm();
```

and after that empty string like this:

```
$(this).children('#com').val('');
```

Comment: i'm not asking to empty the value !! i'm talking about on second post if enter a comment it will refresh the page , the ajax only submitted once !!!

Comment: because you have $("#comment").ajaxForm

Comment: okay i tried using $(".commentFiled").ajaxForm(); now when i post a comment it doesn't add it to the current post. it actually added it to the first one. until i refresh the page.

Comment: do you have multiple target too? like #wtf? if you have, you should change this line: $(this).children('#wtf')

Comment: could you please understand, that the ajaxform works perfectly include clearing the value and blur it. it only works on the first POST. when i go to the second post it doesn't use the ajaxForm instead it uses action="...php" when i change from #comment to ('.commentFiled') it works but it posted it in another post. which is the first one. !

Comment: @user2660611  - the form obviously _doesn't_ work perfectly in that you're trying to ask how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="commentFiled"  method='post' name="comment"  action="func/post_comment.php" >
<input  required type="text"  name="com" placeholder="Write a comment..." class="commentTextField">
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="<?php echo $disid ?>"/>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".commentFiled").each(function(frm){
        var frm = $(this);
        frm.ajaxForm({
            target: frm, 
            success: function() { 
                frm.find('input[name="com"]').val('').blur();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

IDs are unique. jQuery selector will only use the first one found. To work with multiple forms attach your `ajaxForm` plugin to each form, and then work relative to that form. I use the `each()` collection callback to handle each form individually.

Comment: your is working perfect. but it fetch the other comments which are displayed and duplicate them. and instead of frm, i wanna use '#wtf' which if do it will work but the comment will be posted to the first post. any ideas ?

Comment: If you update your question so I can see where #wtf is located, then I'll fix my answer.

Comment: <div id="wtf" class="timeComments">
   <?php include("func/after_refresh.php");?>
   </div>
just before the form. here where i show the comments when the page refreshed.

Comment: and also contain the same html code that echoed by post_comment.php. its just for after refreshing purpose.

Comment: Maybe you just need an inner target instead. `<div class="timeComments"> <?php include("func/after_refresh.php");?> <div id="wtf"></div></div>`